# Change empty alias keytool

Tags: java, keytool, jks, crt

Hi i want change alias using keytool but my initial alias is empty. I want set alias "1" from empty.

```
keytool -changealias -alias "" -destalias "1" -keystore "A:\path\to\key" -storepass Password
```

but then..

Illegal option:  1

Comment: Not quite sure if you copy/pasted the command or not.  I suggest you type it instead and see if it causes errors.

Comment: syntax-wise, command in question works

Comment: @SMA 
keytool -changealias -alias "" -destalias "1" -keystore "M:\Disk\cer.p12" -storepass Password. Illegal option: 1 keytool -changealias [OPTION]... Changes an entry's alias

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be on Windows. If you used the Oracle installer package (not a ZIP or an OpenJDK 'vendor'), check `where keytool` (and maybe `where java` also) to see if it's in a version-specific location like `\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.14\bin` or in a 'generic' location like `\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` or `\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath`. The latter are stubs that forward to the real code in the currently-correct specific location, which may change every time you update, and for `java` I have encountered cases where forwarding 'lost' an empty argument. I've never encountered this with `keytool` -- but I don't think I've ever used an empty argument to `keytool`, so it might have the same problem without my noticing.

If so, try running the 'real' `keytool` program by explicitly specifying the version-specific location.

Comment: I used Keystore Explorer but I need to switch to keytool. Nevermind

It seems to me that this is not the problem because environment variables are ok, when I enter the keytool in cmd, the Key and Certificate Management Tool appears

Commands:

e.t.c.